# Cambiar subquery por Join

Tags: sql

tengo este Select con una subquery que lo hace lento, como puedo convertir la subquery en una consulta con Join.

```
SELECT CAMPO1, 
            CAMPO2,
        CASE WHEN CONDICION='14' THEN (SELECT VALOR 
                                        FROM TABLASUB 
                                        WHERE CODIGO=TABLAMOV.CODIGO
                                             AND FECHA=TABLAMOV.FECHA) 
                                ELSE 0.00 END AS CAMPOOBT
    FROM TABLAMOV
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el código está completo? Porque parece tener errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Es un Select armado, no puedo poner el select real por temas de confidencialidad, pero la idea es esa, quitar la subquery y bajarla al Join, pero tiene esa particularidad de una condicion

Comment: Aun así, deberías de poner código sin errores de sintaxis.

Comment: OK ya lo corregi

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir una subconsulta en un `JOIN` solo tienes que usar los campos relacionados en el `JOIN`

```
SELECT  M.CAMPO1,
        M.CAMPO2,
        CASE WHEN M.CONDICION = '14' THEN S.VALOR ELSE 0.00 END AS CAMPOOBT
FROM TABLAMOV M
--LEFT
JOIN TABLASUB S ON M.CODIGO = S.CODIGO
               AND M.FECHA  = S.FECHA;
```

Dejo comentado el `LEFT` puesto que no sé si haya filas que no estén en la tablasub. Aunque es probable que pudieras incluso agregar la condición de la expresión `CASE` a las condiciones del `JOIN` para eliminar completamente el `CASE`.

```
SELECT  M.CAMPO1,
        M.CAMPO2,
        COALESCE( S.VALOR, 0.00) AS CAMPOOBT
FROM TABLAMOV M
LEFT
JOIN TABLASUB S ON M.CODIGO    = S.CODIGO
               AND M.FECHA     = S.FECHA
               AND M.CONDICION = '14';
```

Comment: De que dependería el eliminar el CASE?

Comment: De que funcione como deseas.

Comment: Ok es que pensé que tenias duda de tu respuesta en el aspecto técnico.

Comment: Me parece que el LEFT JOIN refleja mejor la query original. Mal que mal el resultado de la subconsulta debiera ser NULL y no de plano suprimir esa fila del resultado

Comment: Algun otro comentario please ?