# Cambiar Subquery por JOIN con condicion CASE

Tags: sql, join

Tengo este `Select` con una subquery que lo hace lento, ¿cómo puedo convertir la subquery en una consulta con `Join`?

```sql
SELECT CAMPO1, 
            CAMPO2,
        CASE WHEN CONDICION='14' THEN (SELECT VALOR 
                                        FROM TABLASUB 
                                        WHERE CODIGO=TABLAMOV.CODIGO
                                             AND FECHA=TABLAMOV.FECHA) 
                                ELSE 0.00 END AS CAMPO_OBT
    FROM TABLAMOV
```

Comment: Intenta algo y pásanos el dataset (estructura y datos de muestra) con lo que esperas obtener de la consulta. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambiar subquery por Join](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605190/cambiar-subquery-por-join)

Comment: No responde por eso tuve que crear otra pregunta.

Comment: Ese texto es automático. Se refiere a que tu pregunta es duplicada.

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad sería esta:

```
SELECT M.CAMPO1, M.CAMPO2, S.VALOR AS CAMPO_OBT
FROM TABLAMOV M
LEFT JOIN TABLASUB S ON (M.CODIGO=S.CODIGO) and (M.FECHA=S.FECHA) 
        and (M.CONDICION='14')
```

Las subquerys son poco eficientes frente a las `JOIN`.
En este caso he usado un **LEFT JOIN**, pero dependiendo de los resultados que necesites puedes usar `INNER` o `RIGHT`.  Eso ya no afecta a los datos en si, sino al conjunto de resultado (más grande o menos).

En el caso de **SQLServer** (por ejemplo), si no deseas **NULOS** en la salida, puedes usar `COALESCE`, en otros SGBD's habrá algo similar.

```
SELECT M.CAMPO1, M.CAMPO2, COALESCE(S.VALOR, 0.00) AS CAMPO_OBT
FROM TABLAMOV M
LEFT JOIN TABLASUB S ON (M.CODIGO=S.CODIGO) 
    and (M.FECHA=S.FECHA) and (M.CONDICION='14')
```